# How to write 'seaweed'?

Tags: kanji, readings

This video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8fVS78tvzU) says that seaweed is written like 海草、but Google Translate later told me it's instead 海藻, with 藻 as the second Kanji instead of 草. I know GT shouldn't be trusted, but I Google Image searched 海藻 and got pictures of seaweed, so.. can someone tell me which really means seaweed?

Comment: Apparently, [海草 is "seagrass"](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B5%B7%E8%8D%89#.E6.B5.B7.E8.8D.89.E3.81.A8.E6.B5.B7.E8.97.BB.E3.81.AE.E9.81.95.E3.81.84) while [海藻 is "seaweed" proper](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B5%B7%E8%97%BB).

Answer (score 5):

If you mean edible seaweed, 海藻 is right to use. Nori, wakame, mozuku, hiziki and mekabu are all 海藻. They look like http://bit.ly/1gfJick

In Japan, usually, people don't eat 海草. Dugongs like to eat 海草.   http://www.arkive.org/dugong/dugong-dugon/video-01a.html

海草 is often used to mean 海藻 by mistake.

Answer (score 3):

海藻 = seaweed,

海草 = spermatophyta living in sea (water).

For details, see -> https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B5%B7%E8%97%BB together with https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B5%B7%E8%8D%89.